# MPI Re-Grouping and Broadcasting into Different Communicators

Tags: multiprocessing, mpi, ipc

I want to take a MPI communicator, divide the processes in two groups and have one group scatter its data into the other. I [read](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Comm_split.3.php) how to re-group, but I am concerned that I will not be able to scatter into the other group.

I would like to know if I can simply call `MPI_Scatter` within a process with a communicator that does not contain this process in order to send my process's data to a different group of processes.

Comment: Look up intercommunicators in the MPI standard.

Comment: Split the original communicator and create an intercommunicator from the two subcommunicators using `MPI_Intercomm_create`.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I will accept it to close the questions. Thanks